# Should I be using triggers to connect two related but heavily denormalized tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers, denormalization

I've never used triggers before, but this seems like a solid use case. I'd like to know if triggers are what I should be using, and if so, I could use a little hand-holding on how to go about it.

Essentially **I have two heavily denormalized tables**, `goals` and `users_goals`. Both have `title` columns (`VARCHAR`) that duplicate the `title` data. Thus, there will be one main goal of "Learn how to use triggers", and many (well, maybe not many in this case) users' goals with the same title. The architecture of the site demands that this be the case.

I haven't had a need to have a relationship between these two tables just yet. I link from individual users' goals to the main goals, but simply do so with a query by title, (with an `INDEX` on the `title` column). **Now I need to have a third table that relates these two tables**, but it only needs to be **eventually consistent**. There would be two columns, both `FOREIGN KEY`s, `goal_id` and `users_goal_id`.

Are triggers the way to go with this? And if so, what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could do this using triggers, but the exact implementation depends on your demands.

If you want to rebuild al your queries, so they don't use the title for the join, but the goal_id instead, you can just build that. If you need to keep the titles in sync as well, that's an extra.

First for the join. You stated that one `goal` has many `user goals`. Does that mean that each `user goal` belongs to only one `goal`? If so, you don't need the extra table. You can just add a column `goal_id` to your `user_goals` table. Make sure there is a foreign key constraint (I hope you're using InnoDB tables), so you can enforce referential integrity.

Then the trigger. I'm not exactly sure how to write them on MySQL. I do use triggers a lot on Oracle, but only seldom on MySQL. Anyway, I'd suggest you build three triggers:

1. Update trigger on `goals` table. This trigger should update related `user_goals` table when the title is modified.
2. Update trigger on the `user_goals` table. If `user_goals.title` is modified, this trigger should check if the title in the `goals` table differs from the new title in `user_goals`. If so, you have two options:

   1. Exception: Don't allow the title to be modified in the user_goals child table.
   2. Update: Allow the title to be changed. Update the parent record in goals. The trigger on goals will update the other related user_goals for you.
   3. You could also silently ignore the change by changing the value back in the trigger, but that wouldn't be a good idea.
3. Insert trigger on `user_goals`. Easiest option is to query the title of the specified `goal_id` and don't allow inserting another value for title. You could opt to update `goals` if a title is given.
4. Insert trigger on goals. No need for this one.

Comment: Well, the reason I'm avoiding this sort of architecture is because of the (common) case of title modifications. That's probably the single most common thing a user will be editing about their goals. In which case none of the three sub-choices in your second trigger is ideal. The way it works now is that a new title will be inserted into the `users_goals` table, and if no goal with that title is in `goals`, a goal with that title is created there, as well. Thus, a particular row in `users_goals` will keep the same ID but may go through hundreds of `title` modifications.

Comment: As for your first trigger, I'd also prefer *not* to have the `goals` title be modifiable whenever a user changes the title of their goal in `users_goals`. You can imagine the situation where you have the goal "Learn to sing", I have that goal as well, and I update the title of it to "Learn to sing opera", which then triggers a title change for your goal, as well.

Comment: By the way, I am using InnoDB for everything.

Comment: Ah. Your description of a main goal having many user goals, I interpreted as user_goals a child table of goals. In that case, you could assume there always is a goal (which you could find in the goal_id). You can do that in your situation too, but it may give you some problems in the future. A single typo will create a new goal instead of linking a user_goal to an existing goal. Maybe you'd better modifie your interface as well to allow users to add user_goals to existing goals, or add entirely new user_goals (automatically including their new parent goal).

Comment: "  I'd also prefer not to have the goals title be modifiable whenever a user changes the title of their goal in users_goals. "  Then I don't understand your question. If the titles may differ, then they're not redundant. And if that is the case, what do you want the trigger to do?

Comment: Or do you just want to build the relation between existing goals once by matching the titles?

Comment: Yeah, I realize that typos are a problem, but a relatively unavoidable one unfortunately. And there will be variations on a theme always. But re: your last comment, yes, that's exactly what I want. A relationship between the tables based on the titles, that's only eventually consistent (it doesn't need to be updated immediately). So maybe triggers aren't the right use case here, and something like a cron job is? I'm not sure. And my concern is that lookups by title, even when indexed, is going to be really detrimental to performance.

Comment: Do you need to be able to fix relations afterwards? Say, I change the title from ABCD to EFGH, does that need to update the goal_id also if a goal named EFGH exists? And if it doesn't exist, does it need to create a new goal, or should it just stick with the goal it doesn't match with. Rules like this will cause your application to seem like magic, because goal relations may seem to randomly change.  I think it's best to first think what the exact rules are for linking and unlinking/relinking goals, and after that determine if you need to enforce these rules in triggers or in a cron job.

Comment: Only minor changes to you application interface allow more strict rules and make your life a lot easier. F.i. always make the user select a parent goal or 'new goal' when creating a user goal will create the relationship at the moment of creation. It doesn't ever need to change afterwards. You only need a one-time update statement to create existing relationships.  But you need to be able to make those changes to your application...

Answer (score 1):

No, you should never use triggers at all if you can avoid it.

Triggers are an anti-pattern to me; they have the effect of "doing stuff behind the programmer's back".

Imagine a future maintainer of your application needs to do something, if they are not aware of the trigger (imagine they haven't checked your database schema creation scripts in detail), then they could spend a long, long time trying to work out why this happens.

If you need to have several pieces of client-side code updating the tables, consider making them use a stored procedure; document this in the code maintenance manual (and comments etc) to ensure that future developers do the same.

If you can get away with it, just write a common routine on the client side which is always called to update the shared column(s).

Even triggers do nothing to ensure that the columns are always in sync, so you will need to implement a periodic process which checks this anyway. They will otherwise go out of sync sooner or later (maybe just because some operations engineer decides to start doing manual updates; maybe one table gets restored from a backup and the other doesn't)